# What is the benefit of using a ref on a service?

Tags: vue.js

Consider these two approaches of calling a service in a Vue 3 Component (composition API)

Direct usage:

```
import productService from '@/services/product.service';
productService.getProducts().then(data => products.value = data);
```

Wrapped in a ref:

```
import productService from '@/services/product.service';
const productService = ref(new ProductService());
productService.value.getProducts().then(data => products.value = data);
```

I stumbled upon the second variant in the [docs of PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/dataview)

**Is there any benefit of using a ref over a direct usage?**

Comment: There's no benefit. A ref makes sense only if it's value is supposed to be changed at some point, which is not the case here.

Comment: All right. Post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I wonder if that's a practice that was intended so ProductService could be substituted in testing. We don't see it used as such, and there are better patterns for testing seams that don't require actually instantiating a ProductService, but that's one of the few things I can think of. (I checked the React Hooks source in case this was a naïve port of a persistent service there, but even that one just instantiates a new ProductService every render cycle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref object is used for the cases when a value is reassigned in other place and can be read in another place, the pattern makes use of the fact that objects are passed by reference rather than by value in JavaScript.

Since `productService` value is never changed, there's no benefit from using a ref.